# Envio de e-mail com Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, email

Estou tendo problemas para enviar e-mail com laravel 5.2.
Está me retornando este erro:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", 
with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

O arquivo `.env` está assim:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@nomedaempresa.org.br
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

O domínio de emails da empresa está hospedado no Google. Consigo logar normal no gmail com o e-mail e a senha que botei no `.env`.

O arquivo `config/mail.php` está assim:

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'user@nomedaempresa.org.br', 'name' => 'teste'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('user@nomedaempresa.org.br'),
    'password' => env('****'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

Estou enviando email assim:

```
Mail::send('emails.recuperar-senha', $dados, function ($message) {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'));
});
```

Comment: Você está testando isso local ou na web ?

Comment: Estou tentando localmente.

Comment: Eu li "loucamente". Rsrsrs Eu tenho esse problema aqui no meu Localhost. Não consigo enviar nada por e-mail. Sempre testo no servidor e funciona. Para fazer um teste, troque o driver de **smtp** para **mail**.

Comment: Já encontrei o problema. É com o email. Precisa dar uma permissão para envio de SMTP por estar em um domínio diferente de google.com

Answer (score 3):

Para garantir que tudo está correto e identificar o erro de autenticação criei um e-mail de teste no gmail:

Para teste altere o arquivo `config/mail` da seguinte forma:

```
return [
   'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
   'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
   'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
   'from' => ['teste' => 'stackteste8@gmail.com','name' => 'teste'],
   'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
   'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','stackteste8@gmail.com'),
   'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','testeti1'),
   'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


];
```

e para envio:

```
\Mail::send('emails.recuperar-senha',$dados, function ($message)use($request){
        $message->from(\Config::get('mail.from.teste'))
                ->to('seuemailpessoal@gmail.com')
                ->subject('Assunto do e-mail');
    });
```

Fiz os testes com essa configuração e enviou normalmente.

Comment: Alterei o código conforme você disse, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, altera os dados de e-mail no local colocando seu e-mail pessoal e tenta enviar para você mesmo. Já que é erro de autenticação. Para ver se não é alguma configuração no e-mail.

Comment: Já tentei isso, deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta com um e-mail de teste que cadastrei no gmail e enviou normalmente.

Comment: Já encontrei o problema. É com o email. Precisa dar uma permissão para envio de SMTP por estar em um domínio diferente de google.com

Comment: Recomendo que você use o MailTrap para fazer seus testes.
https://mailtrap.io/